# Log into steam with Python 3 not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, urllib, steam

I'm trying to log into the steam website with Python 3 as follows:

```
import urllib
import http.cookiejar

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
authentication_url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/login/'
payload = {
    'username': 'myusername',
    'password': 'mypassword',
    'captcha_text' : ''
}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
binary_data = data.encode('UTF-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(authentication_url, binary_data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
contents = resp.read()
print(contents)
```

However when I print the contents it prints the login page... I know for sure that my login credentials are correct.

Also, what I find weird that in the form there is a 'captcha_text', but when I visit the browser via internet explorer/chrome I can't see this. What should I fill in for this variable?

Comment: I doubt anyone can tell you how to fill in a captcha that they cannot see

Comment: You misunderstood what I said @PadraicCunningham ; I said, there is no actual captcha on the page but still it's included in the form. Why is that and what do I need to fill in that data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you login manually, you'll see (in your browser's Dev tools) that the actual login request is made to this URL:

```
https://store.steampowered.com/login/dologin/
```

And below is a screenshot of the form data sent

[image]

In the above screenshot, you may notice that the password isn't sent raw. They hash the password using RSA key and something else. They've made it quite difficult to login with a script.

#### Breakdown of how login at Steam works

1. When you press the Sign in button of login form, first request is made to receive RSA key, timestamp, some sort of token, etc at - `https://store.steampowered.com/login/getrsakey/`
2. Then they hash the password
3. Then another request is made at - `https://store.steampowered.com/login/dologin/` to actually log you in.